# How to iterate simoultaneusly throught two sets in SAS?

Tags: sas

I've tried something like this :

```
data wynik;
set dane;
if x>3 than x3=3*x;
else set dane2; x3=x2;set dane;
run;
```

dane and dane2 have the same number of rows

result is interesting - condition `x>3` is still holding after setting dane2, but SAS always takes first observation - that is, it doesn't pass the current state of hidden loop counter. Make question is - does SAS have/use hidden loop with counter while iterating through dataset which could be accessed by user ?

editon :
mayby I should add in title - without expicit loops, but this would also be welcomed

Comment: If one of the tables isn't too big you could also possibly use a hash object and manually iterate through it.

Comment: @Rob Penridge what is the best introducion to sas hash object for non programmers ;

Comment: I would start with the examples given on this tip sheet (http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/dot/hash-tip-sheet.pdf).  Then these two papers give excellent examples of the flexibility of hash tables (http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/236-30.pdf) and (http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/029-2008.pdf).  If you are relatively comfortable coding then hash tables can be amazing and they aren't as scary as they look!  Looking at some of your other posts I imagine you'll be fine.  BTW - that tip sheet is my go-to resource whenever I have a hash table dcoumentation question.

Answer (score 3):

Making some assumptions:

```
data dane;
do x = 1 to 5;
output;
end;
run;

data dane2;
do x2 = 5 to 1 by -1;
output;
end;
run;

data wynik;
merge dane dane2;
if x > 3 then x3=3*x;
else x3=x2;
put x3=;
run;
```

That uses the side-by-side merge (merge with no by statement) to get you both values at once.

To answer your followup question:

> does SAS have/use hidden loop with counter while iterating through dataset which could be accessed by user ?

Yes, it does; `_n_` defines the current loop iteration (as long as it isn't modified externally, which it can be - it is just a regular variable that's not written out to the dataset).  So you could similarly do the following:

```
data wynik;
set dane;
if x > 3 then x3=x*3;
else do;
  set dane2 point=_n_;
  x3=x2;
end;
put x3=;
run;
```

The side-by-side merge is preferred because it will be faster, unless you very infrequently need to look at DANE2.  It's also easier to code.

Comment: It goes without saying that both of these risk the same problem - variable overlap.  If any variables overlap between the two datasets, you need to verify that you're getting what you expect, or use DROP, KEEP, or RENAME statements to make sure that happens.